# How to populate States and Country picklists or achieve similar kind of functionality on lightning form components?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I have created a contact info edit form with lightning component. I intend to provide users a States and country picklist functionality on form like we already have in salesforce. Is there any work around to achieve this?